# Do Mysql slaves run multiple threads to read Relay log for sync up Master's operation

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I know Mysql slaves read Master's bin-log sequentially with single thread and dump the data as relay log locally. My question is that will slave use multiple threads to read the relay logs for sync up the operations(Insert,Update,Delete)?
If it's not multiple threads, I guess the following scenario Mysql slave may not be able to catch up the Master forever.

Let's say Master has 100 tables and there is no any relationship between them. So It could be 100 writing requests to the 100 table simultaneous. If we suppose in 1 second the 100 tables finish writing in Master, then Slave may need 100 seconds to finish the sync up if it's single thread operation. Right please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using MySQL Server 5.6 or later, then yes, the replication events are executed sequentially by a single thread (the "SQL" thread) after having been received from the master by the "IO" thread and written to the relay log.

However, MySQL 5.6 introduced [`slave_parallel_workers`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_slave-parallel-workers), which, if configured (along with other prerequisites for multithreaded replication) allows multiple (theoretically up to 1024) parallel replication worker threads, controlled and coordinated by the slave SQL thread, so that queries among independent databases can be replicated in parallel.

Comment: so theoretically, if Master keeping writing/updating parallel, and never having rest, then the distance between Master and Slave would be bigger and bigger. Unless Master has time to get some rest, then Slave just get chance to catch up, right please?

Comment: Theoretically, sort of.  There are factors that make it not quite so straightforward.  The master can only do so much disk access while doing those "parallel" writes and it also has to do disk access for its read workload, which the slave may not have to support.  With sufficient disk throughput available, an appripriately-sized slave for the workload often has no problem keeping up with the master.

Answer (score 0):

It uses one reading thread and one updating thread.

Your scenario doesn't make sense. The 100 updates will take as long at the master as at the slave, maybe longer, unless there is a remarkable discrepancy between the CPUs and disks of the master and slave hosts.

Comment: I couldn't understand, why "maybe longer"? We can suppose they are using same hardware. I think the slave should be 100 times longer than Master, right please? because Master was parallel writing while slave was one thread sequential writing. Thanks!